# Why do, re, mi notation is variable

Tags: sheet-music

I get following quote from https://www.musiah.com/articles/equipment-tips/piano-lessons-or-keyboard-lessons-what-is-the-difference.html

> In the key of C Major, C is “do”; but in the key of G Major, G is
>   “do”. A student who cannot identify middle C on the piano has not been
>   taught piano properly, in my view.

I'm very newbie and just learning music theory, Normally we use `do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, si` in Turkey. Since I learn music from international resources. I directly mapped with `C D E F G A B`. But, once I read that I couldn't really understand this variability. I confused.

Could you please explain what does it mean ?

Is that also mean reading following notes as `G A B C D E F G` instead of `C D E F G A B C` in key of G Major ?

[image: C D E F G A B C]